# How to add border around QWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am using `PyQT4` to create a sample application for a prospective client. I am looking for some way to put a border around a specific widget. Please give me some pointers to look for.

updated :

```
class CentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, mainWindow):
        super(CentralWidget, self).__init__()

        self.create(mainWindow)
```

Above code defines the widget.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the stylesheet documentation, QWidget does not support the border property (but it seems to have changed since this answer was originally published, in 2011).

If your widget is a container of other widgets, then you should use QFrame, as it will allow you to call `setFrameStyle` and `setLineWidth`. It is preferable over calling `setStyleSheet`, since style-sheet will make all child widgets inherit the border property.

Here it is a complete example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class CentralWidget(QtGui.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(CentralWidget, self).__init__(*args)
        # use for a non-contaner widget
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,0,0); margin:5px; border:1px solid rgb(0, 255, 0); ")
        # use for a container widget
        self.setFrameStyle(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Plain)
        self.setLineWidth(1)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    w = CentralWidget(mw)
    mw.setCentralWidget(w)
    mw.show()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Setting up the style sheet for the QTFrame sets all same style for all the child widgets. It seems the method in `QFrame` `setFrameStyle()` works well.

Comment: You can add a selector to the style sheet string to target only one class of widget e.g. `"QFrame {background-color: rgb(255,0,0);}"`

Comment: All child widgets inherit this style, you end up with all the widgets being surrounded by a border

Answer (score 3):

you can use setFramStyle like this

```
 self.setFrameStyle(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Plain)
 self.setLineWidth(1)
```

for more information check the following link
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QFrame.html